# XSLT: Dynamic node name insertion based on template parameter

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to generate the following structure in an XSLT template.

```
<ns:e1>
   <child1>some value<child1>
   <child2>some value<child2>
   <child3>some value<child3>
</ns:e1>
```

or

```
<ns:e2>
   <child1>some value<child1>
   <child2>some value<child2>
   <child3>some value<child3>
</ns:e2>
```

or other elements ns:e3 etc (although finite), based on a template parameter (say `type`). Typically I could use an `xls:choose` construct. In such a case, I would be duplicating the child elements (whose values are also template parameters).

Is there a way in XSLT to dynamically assume the element name `ns:e1` or `ns:e2` so that I can put the child elements once in its parent. I could save maintenance effort later if I have change the child elements or values (change once in one place and avoid bugs due to human errors).

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may use the `xsl:element` instruction to do that.

Assuming you always want to have `<child1>some value<child1><child2>some value<child2><child3>some value<child3>` as children for your parent element, you could rewrite your code like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="elementName">
  <!-- compute the element name here ... -->
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Here we create an element having the name computed in variable elementName -->
<xsl:element name="{$elementName}" namespace="http://www.anamespace.com/and/so/on">
   <child1>some value<child1>
   <child2>some value<child2>
   <child3>some value<child3>
</xsl:element>
```